# WPF TextBlock get lines after textwrapping

Tags: wpf, textblock, fixeddocument, line-count

I have `FixedDocument` page and I want to place `TextBlock` on it, but it can be that `Textblock` doesn't fit on page by height. 
So I want to take lines from generated `TextBlock` with `TextWrapping`, and then create new `TextBlock`, that fitted by height and place it on page. 
`TextBlock` have `LineCount` private property, that mean that it has `TextLines` after wrapping and I can somehow get it. 
Creating `TextBlock` with runs:

```
public TextItem(PageType pageType, Run[] runs, Typeface typeFace, double fontSize)
        : base(pageType)
{
     this.TextBlock = new TextBlock();
     this.TextBlock.Inlines.AddRange(runs);
     if (typeFace != null)
          this.TextBlock.FontFamily = typeFace.FontFamily;

     if (fontSize > 0)
           this.TextBlock.FontSize = fontSize;
     this.TextBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;   //wrapping
}
```

Creating `TextBlock` with text:

```
public TextItem(PageType pageType, String text, Typeface typeFace, double fontSize)
        : base(pageType)
{
    if (typeFace == null || fontSize == 0)
        throw new Exception("Wrong textitem parameters");

    this.TextBlock = new TextBlock();
    this.TextBlock.Text = text;
    this.TextBlock.FontFamily = typeFace.FontFamily;
    this.TextBlock.FontSize = fontSize;
    this.TextBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    this.TextBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;

    this.TypeFace = typeFace;
}
```

Set width to `TextBlock` and get `DesiredSize` :

```
this.TextBlock.Width = document.CurrentPage.Content.ActualWidth;
this.TextBlock.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b6cZD5pp I know one way to get lines from textblock, but this only work when control was already drawned.

Comment: Have you looked at the wpf `FlowDocument`? A link to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but FlowDocument does not suitable for me. I`m try layout elements manual on single FixedPage, that have A4 size. That`s why i need to split textblock if it does not fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the exactly same problem, and for some time, I lost the hope and I thought there is no solution for this.
BUT, I was wrong, there are many solutions for that (At least three) 
And you are right, one of them use the `LineCount` property by using reflection.
And the second using it is own algorithm to get the lines.
And the third, which is preferred to me, has very elegant way to get the result which you want.

Please refer to this question, to see the three answers of this.
[Get the lines of the TextBlock according to the TextWrapping property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378441/)

---

Here is a copy of the best solution (in my opinion)

```
public static class TextUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetLines(this TextBlock source)
    {
        var text = source.Text;
        int offset = 0;
        TextPointer lineStart = source.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        do
        {
            TextPointer lineEnd = lineStart != null ? lineStart.GetLineStartPosition(1) : null;
            int length = lineEnd != null ? lineStart.GetOffsetToPosition(lineEnd) : text.Length - offset;
            yield return text.Substring(offset, length);
            offset += length;
            lineStart = lineEnd;
        }
        while (lineStart != null);
    }
}
```